# How can I find the inverse function over the interval$ [0,\infty].$?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

How can I find the inverse function of this function $ y = x^3 + \sqrt{x}$, could anyone give me a hint please?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you looking for an inverse?

Comment: This was a question in an exam@Dylan

Comment: The exact question asked to fine the inverse? Or was it something else that relates to the property of the inverse?

Comment: $ x = y^3 + \sqrt {y}$ is the inverse function. Just swap $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^3 + \sqrt x = y$ becomes $x^6 - 2yx^3 - x + y^2 = 0$, whose Galois group is $S_6$, so it is not solvable by radicals.

That means, the inverse function exists, but you cannot express it using surds.

---

By computation (thanks to PARI/GP), the Galois group of $x^6 - 6x^3 - x + 9 = 0$ is $S_6$. This is the same polynomial but with $y=3$.

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \varepsilon, \zeta$ be the six roots of $x^6 - 6x^3 - x + 9 = 0$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Let $y_1$ through $y_6$ be the six roots of $x^6 - 2yx^3 - x + y^2 = 0$ over $\Bbb Q(y)$.

We know that $[\Bbb Q(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\varepsilon,\zeta) : \Bbb Q] = 720$.

It suffices to show that $[\Bbb Q(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5,y_6) : \Bbb Q(y)] = 720$.

---

Note that $\Bbb Q(y) \subseteq \Bbb Q(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5,y_6)$ because $2y = \displaystyle \sum y_1 y_2 y_3$ (Vieta).

---

We will, in particular, show that this path and the indices are correct:

$$\Bbb Q(y) \overset 6 \longrightarrow \Bbb Q(y,y_1) \overset 5 \longrightarrow \Bbb Q(y,y_1,y_2) \overset 4 \longrightarrow \Bbb Q(y,y_1,y_2,y_3) \\ \overset 3 \longrightarrow \Bbb Q(y,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4) \overset 2 \longrightarrow \Bbb Q(y,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5) = \Bbb Q(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5,y_6)$$

where $\longrightarrow$ means nothing more than field extension and the number above is the degree of the extension.

---

$x^6 - 2yx^3 - x + y^2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(y)$ because $x^6 - 6x^3 - x + 9$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. Therefore, $\Bbb Q(y,y_1)$ is $\Bbb Q(y)[X]/\langle X^6 - 2yX^3 - X + y^2 \rangle$ which is a degree $6$ extension of $\Bbb Q(y)$.

---

$\displaystyle \frac {x^6 - 2yx^3 - x + y^2} {x - y_1}$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(y,y_1)$ because $\displaystyle \frac {x^6 - 6x^3 - x + 9} {x - \alpha}$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$. They are both degree $5$ polynomials, so indeed we have $[\Bbb Q(y,y_1,y_2):\Bbb Q(y)] = 5$.

(For reference:
$$\begin{array}{cl}
&\displaystyle \frac {x^6 - 2yx^3 - x + y^2} {x - y_1} \\
&\displaystyle = x^5 + y_1 x^4 + y_1^2 x^3 - (2y-y_1^3) x^2 - (2yy_1-y_1^4) x + (-1-2yy_1^2+y_1^5)
\end{array}$$
because $(-1-2yy_1^2+y_1^5)(-y_1) = -y_1^6 + 2yy_1^3 + y_1 = y^2$.)

---

The fact that $[\Bbb Q(y,y_1,y_2,y_3) : \Bbb Q(y,y_1,y_2)] = 4$, that $[\Bbb Q(y,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4) : \Bbb Q(y,y_1,y_2,y_3)] = 3$, and that $[\Bbb Q(y,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5) : \Bbb Q(y,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)] = 2$ follow similarly.

Comment: what do you mean by surds?

Comment: it means it is not possible to simplify the inverse using any already defined functions: the most reduced form of "the inverse of $x^3+\sqrt x=y$" is "the solution of $x^6 - 2yx^3 - x + y^2 = 0$ for $x$, i.e. $x=\text{root}(x^6 - 2yx^3 - x + y^2)$". or something along those lines

Comment: even on the interval mentioned in the title of the question?

Comment: I don't understand how you got your sextic. Just let $t = \sqrt{x}$ and you get $t^6+t = y$. Also, how did you get the Galois group?

Comment: what do you want to say @user21820? do you mean that it has an inverse?

Comment: @Intuition: I was asking Kenny, as was obvious from my comment...

Comment: @user21820   :( :( :(  but the question is mine this is why I am asking you ..... hahaha

Comment: But my comment is mine. You asked me what I wanted to say, but I had already said what I wanted to say. Until Kenny replies, I just have nothing else to say... lol.

Comment: @user21820 I got my sextic by not substituting. Also, I got my Galois group from noticing that $y=3$ gives $S_6$ (courtesy PARI/GP) and thought that the Galois group for the generic polynomial should also be $S_6$. I am aware that this is potentially dangerous, but as you know it is quite hard to compute Galois groups, especially for generic polynomials.

Comment: @KennyLau: Ah I didn't notice that you can put $\sqrt{x}$ on one side. Can you believe it? And yes I asked about the Galois group because indeed I thought it was difficult to compute it. I think, however, that you would be correct in your conclusion about the Galois group, but I don't know how to prove it. You can make your answer definitely correct by just stating that if the polynomial was solvable by radicals then the one with $y=3$ would too, which is impossible if PARI/GP is right.